# How to use azure key vault with ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-keyvault

I am planning to use azure key vault for my MVC web app application. I want to save some secrets values into the key vault, which currently i have saved in web.config file.

I have created key vault with the secrets, but facing problem to call that key vault in mvc web app application.

I have gone through some tutorials but all are showing the examples with .net core only.

Can anybody suggest  How I can consume key vault in my mvc .net framework application?

Comment: I found a section "Access your secrets (ASP.NET)" in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service

Comment: @PeterB Is there any other way we can use key vault without adding connected service? for example - .net sdk

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets/samples/Sample1_HelloWorld.md

Comment: @RakeshKumar DO you have any other concerns?